# Extra Markers in Graph Legend

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, legend

I can't figure out why my legend shows three of each marker (where I only want one).

Googling/stackoverflow led me to `numpoints = 1`, however my problem still persists. any ideas or suggestions?

code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

.....

markers = ["o", "s", "d", "v"]
for i in range(4):
    plt.scatter([j for j in range(1,7)],
                ygroup[i],
                s = 38,
                c = colours[i],
                marker = markers[i],
                edgecolors='none',
                label = instloop[i])

ax.legend(loc = 'best', numpoints = 1)
show()
```

picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special keyword argument for scatter plots - you want to pass `scatterpoints=1` to `ax.legend()`

Comment: oh thank you both. that was simple... i feel a little silly -_-